# How to turn properties of class into parameters?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

### Background

I'm working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 QueryExpressions, which for all you non-CRM people out there, just know that I'm working with an SDK to access a database that requires you to put the string names of the columns you are selecting in a custom ColumnSet class:

```
new ColumnSet("personid", "name", "age");
```

The SDK does generate early bound classes so I do have classes for all the database tables, and the early bound classes all have a dictionary whose key are the columns of the table that have been populated on the object. ie:

```
var p = new Person { Name = "John", Age = 39, SSN = null };
p.Attributes.Count == 3;
// p.Attributes.Keys == { "name", "age", "ssn" };
```

### The Problem

I have three issues when populating the ColumnSet

1. I forget what columns a class/table contains
2. I fat finger some of the columns and don't get an error until runtime
3. The column Names all have to be lower case when instantiating the ColumnSet, which makes for poor readability ie `thissillyexampleisntthatreadable` vs `ThisSillyExampleIsntThatReadable`

All three of these issues can be solved by early binding.

I know I can create an enum or stuct for each class that contains all of a class's columns ie: new ColumnSet(PersonColumns.PersonId, PersonColumns.Name, PersonColumns.Age), but I want it to use the classes that have already been generated.

### My Best Attempt

The best that I can currently come up with is this:

```
ColumnSetFactory.Create<Person>(p => p.PersonId = null, p.Name = null, p.Age = null);
```

Where Create accepts an object of type T (person in this example) and then inspects the dictionary of the object to generate and return the ColumnSet.

### The Goal

Have a generic function that utilizes the early bound classes to generate the ColumnSet:

```
ColumnSetFactory.Create<Person>(p => p.PersonId, p.Name, p.Age);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt/goal syntax does not work in C# unfortunately, but you could probably get something close to it.

I'm not familiar with the dynamics crm so I'm making this assumption, the constructor for `ColumnSet` takes a variable amount of string arguments and has a signature:

```
public ColumnSet(params string[] arguments)
```

---

You could create a lambda expression that returns an object initializer (to create an anonymous object) and use some reflection to invoke the constructor using the initializer's member bindings.  If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, you want to use existing parameter names of an object to essentially pass those names to this constructor to create the object.

Here's how you can do that:

```
public static ColumnSet Create<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> parameters)
{
    var initializer = parameters.Body as NewExpression;
    if (initializer == null || initializer.Members == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("lambda must return an object initializer");
    var memberNames = initializer.Members
        .Select(member => member.Name.ToLower())
        .ToArray();
    var ctor = typeof(ColumnSet).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string[]) });
    return (ColumnSet)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { memberNames });
}
```

Then to use it, call it like this:

```
ColumnSetFactory.Create<Person>(p => new { p.PersonId, p.Name, p.Age });

// Personally I prefer to call it like this to let the compiler
// infer the generic arguments
ColumnSetFactory.Create((Person p) => new { p.PersonId, p.Name, p.Age });
```

Which would generate an equivalent call to the constructor:

```
new ColumnSet("personid", "name", "age");
```

You could even make up column names and give them random values, the values themselves will not be used, just the name of the member.

```
ColumnSetFactory.Create<Person>(p => new
{
    p.PersonId,
    p.Name,
    p.Age,
    Foobar = 0,
    Boo = "rawr!!!",
});
```

Which would generate an equivalent call to the constructor:

```
new ColumnSet("personid", "name", "age", "foobar", "boo");
```

Comment: You are correct that the constructor for ColumnSet is ColumnSet(params string[] arguments).

Answer (score 0):

There are several moving parts here.

First, with C# you are wanting early bound items with late bound execution and unfortunately you can't get there the way you want.  Early bound builds a class prior to compile time.

So one option would be to create your own simplified early bound creation for the few entities you want (or use the Microsoft early bound stuff)

Another option is to use a Dictionary - but this will probably prove to be more tedious and only takes care of issue #3.

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I'd take a step back and look at using Fetch.

With a tool like stunnware, you can easily create your fetch query and test it so that you get the results you're looking for.

Then just create a generic function to execute fetch to return an IList>.  This way, you can easily reference the fields based on the attributes you specified inside the fetch.  (Taking care of issues #1 & #2)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by needing late bound execution...  I already have all the classes built via the CrmSrvcUtil.  I'm assuming by Fetch, you mean Fetch xml? Just wondering how do you store your fetch XML? Is it stored as a compiled string directly in your C# class or do you store it as XML files that get loaded when needed?